# What are the corresponding action names between IntelliJ IDEA and Visual Studio + ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, resharper, keymapping

For example, IntelliJ IDEA's keymap action `Main menu -> Edit -> Copy reference` would map to `ReSharper_CopyFqn` action in Visual Studio keyboard setup. Is there a more complete list somewhere? Ideally, the list should also contain key shortcuts which I could edit and import to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have attempted to map IntelliJ commands to Visual Studio commands and have an XML file that provides Visual Studio keyboard bindings based on my mappings.
I have include additional information in the comments about how closely the various Visual Studio features align with the IntelliJ commands.

You can view the IntelliJ-VisualStudio keyboard mapping file here:
https://github.com/justcla/KeyBindings/blob/master/KeyboardSchemes/VSSettings/IntelliJ.vssettings